# Omnisharp error about dotnet version - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

at VSCode launch today I'm receiving this error:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 27/5/2022, 12:37:25
    Target: f:\UnityProjects\MyGame.sln
[ERROR] Error: Found dotnet version 5.0.407. Minimum required version is 6.0.100.
```

I read that there have been updates in omnisharp but I really don't know how to fix the issue.
I've installed dotnet 6.0 TLS through a new visual studio installation... is there anything else I can do to bring dotnet working with my Unity project?

Comment: What does `dotnet --version` say?

Comment: @shingo actually it says 5.0.407... I've run the visual studio installer selecting dotnet 6.0 TLS :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using C# extension 1.25.0 or higher, they announced a change in the extension's details page:

> .NET Framework builds of OmniSharp no longer ship with Mono or the
> MSBuild tooling (See announcement omnisharp-roslyn#2339). To ensure
> that the C# extension remains usable out of the box for .NET SDK
> projects, we have changed the default value of omnisharp.useModernNet
> to true.
>
> If you still need Unity or .NET Framework support, you can set
> `omnisharp.useModernNet` to `false` in your VS Code settings and restart
> OmniSharp.

Changing that `omnisharp.useModernNet` setting to `false` worked for me.

Comment: Huh, so crazy that they disabled Unity support for C# by default! Seems to be a misguided assumption that people won't need it...

Comment: I think it's because of the move to 6.0+ and the launch of VS 2022 which includes .NET 6. Definitely an inconvenience. I am updating VS Mac to see if I can resolve it without configuration changes

Answer (score 4):

If you use vscode for **web development** and your installed dotnet **SDK version is < 6**, this answer might be useful.

After quite some time I spotted an Ominisharp Log warning this.

```bash
[ERROR] Error: Found dotnet version 3.1.419. Minimum required version is 6.0.100.
```

---

### Solution

Install dotnet SDK 6 alongside or by replacing your current version.

I recommend you install it by using the [dotnet-install.{sh | ps1}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) script.

By running the command below it will install the latest version alongside your current one.

`sudo ./dotnet-install.sh -c 6.0 --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet`

```bash
~ » dotnet --list-sdks                                                                                                       
3.1.419 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.300 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```